# What happens to the attraction of glycerol to a positively charged acetate rod if water is added

Tags: organic-chemistry, solutions, intermolecular-forces

I know that glycerol is more polar than water because it has stronger intermolecular forces and its also more viscous. If I were to add water to a glycerol solution, would the solution get less polar with weaker intermolecular forces? Also if I were to add water, would the solution be more attracted to a positively ...

I mean if I place a positively charged acetate rod next to the mixed solution of water and glycerol, would the solution get more attracted to the rod or less attracted or would there be no change?

Comment: This is a *non sequitur*: "I know that glycerol is more polar than water because it has stronger intermolecular forces and its also more viscous." Polarity is determined by distribution of charges on a molecule. Mineral oil is viscous but not polar.

Comment: A good rule of thumb (as long as you don't work with $\ce{HF}$) is that **nothing** is more polar than water.

Comment: Ok, but what happens if I mix water and glycerol? Does the solution get more attracted to the acetate rod or less attracted and why?